# Add a scroll bar for dropdown menu with search bar

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar, dropdown

This is my HTML code

```
                <div class="location-dropdown dropdown">
                    <button onclick="locations_dropdown()" class="dropbtn" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">{{site_network_status['sitename']}}</button>
                    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
                        <div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="link1">link1</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link2</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And this is my js code used to show all the options and let user search.

```
function locations_dropdown() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }
  
  function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        a[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        a[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
```

this works fine. But I have way too many option links in the dropdown menu. So i want an option to be able to scroll through those options. i only want to be able to show around 10 options and scroll from that down.

Any help will be appreciated.

Update

this is the css file i am using.

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
  }
  
  #myInput {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 14px 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  
  #myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}
  
  .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 230px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
  
  .show {display: block;}
```

Comment: Can you also put your css code so that it can be tested?  did you test **overflowflow: auto**?

Comment: @AbolfazlAlmas i have updated my question with the css code.

Comment: For this possibility, you should consider max-height ten times the height of each option and set overflow to auto.I will put the sample in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add scrolable-container class and style it.

```css
h1,
h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {
  outline: 3px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  min-width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.scrolable-container {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 420px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="location-dropdown dropdown">
<button onclick="locations_dropdown()" class="dropbtn" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">{{site_network_status['sitename']}}</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <div class="scrolable-container">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link1">link1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link3</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link4</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link5</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link6</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link7</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link8</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link9</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link10</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link11</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link12</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link13</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link14</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link15</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="link2">link16</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
  function locations_dropdown() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }
  
  function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        a[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        a[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
```